# IE not showing <li> within <ul> (z-index issue?)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

Hey guys, I've been debugging for IE7/IE8 all day and there is one issue that is doing my head in :/

Ive got an unordered list, that is powered by a jquery carousel, showing images. But for some reason IE shows the `<ul>`  container but not its `<li>` contents.

Now I'm familiar with the IE z-index issue. I thought this was easily fixable by giving the list item a z-index higher than the unordered list but this doesn't seem to work.

It displays the way it should in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, it's just IE that is acting strange (as always :/.)

You can view the issue at http://www.fronttaal.nl/clients/front-taal-gold/prinsenhof just look for the slide-up carousel at the bottom of the main content.

In this case i've put a red border around the `<ul>` and a green border around the `<li>`, adding a `z-index: 9997;` to the `<ul>` and a `z-index:9998;` to the `<li>` to make sure it wouldnt interfere with other z-indexes.

I hope one of you coding gods can nudge me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: You have [49 errors and 5 warnings](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fronttaal.nl%2Fclients%2Ffront-taal-gold%2Fprinsenhof&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) in the HTML alone. (I didn't [validate the CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).) Fix those first, then you can look further.

Comment: Regarding `z-index`, note that [each positioned element starts a new `z-index` space for its positioned descendants](http://phrogz.net/CSS/zIndex.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, do both the ul and li have postion attributes?

Comment: Hey Timbadu, yep, i gave them both a relative position